# webpack-cli : Error: spawn Unknown system error -86 / Symfony6 / Mac M1

Tags: php, npm, webpack-encore, symfony6, webpack-cli

I have a mac with M1 chip and I wonder if the error is related to this, because on my old one I have no problem.

```
 % npm run dev           

> dev
> encore dev

Running webpack ...

[webpack-cli] Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
    at Object.execFile (node:child_process:348:17)
    at module.exports.fileCommandJson (/Users/Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/node-notifier/lib/utils.js:88:13)
    at NotificationCenter.notifyRaw (/Users/Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/notificationcenter.js:81:11)
    at WebpackNotifierPlugin.compilationDone (/Users/Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/webpack-notifier/index.js:129:14)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:18:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at /Users//Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:498:23
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/Desktop/quest/wild-series/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:919:5) {
  errno: -86,
  code: 'Unknown system error -86',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

I tried whith yarn and with npm..

Answer (score 6):

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/realm-cli-unknown-system-error-86/204900/4

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue while switching to the new M1 chip.

The problem come from node-notifier dependencies from webpack-notifier package that isn't working on M1 chip : https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/issues/361

To solve the issue you can remove or comment `.enableBuildNotifications()` from webpack.config.js. You won't receive any notification in case of build fail but you'll be able to build / watch again !

Best.